# RegEx for capturing a word in between = and ;

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to select `word2` from the following :

```
word2;word3
```

`word2` that is between `;` and start of the line unless there is a `=` in between. In that case, I want start from the `=` instead of the start of the line
like `word2` from

```
word1=word2;word3
```

I have tried using this regex

```
(?<=\=|^).*?(?=;)
```

which select the `word2` from

```
word2;word3
```

but also the whole `word1=word2` from

```
word1=word2;word3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an optional group to check for a word followed by an equals sign and capture the value in the first capturing group:

```
^(?:\w+=)?(\w+);
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\w+=)?` Optional non capturing group matching 1+ word chars followed by `=`
- `(\w+)` Capture in the first capturing group 1+ word chars
- `;` Match `;`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN2bl4/2/)

In .NET you might also use:

```
(?<=^(?:\w+=)?)\w+(?=;)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b%3d%29%3f%29%5cw%2b%28%3f%3d%3b%29&i=word2%3bword3%0d%0aword1%3dword2%3bword3&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/dUzYIS)

[image]

Comment: thanx . Is there a way to return group 1 directly from the regex.?

Comment: @Krinjon The second pattern will give you the match only instead of the group, although the group option has the advantage to not use lookarounds. For example https://ideone.com/dUzYIS

Answer (score 2):

There should be so many options, maybe regular expressions among the last ones.

But, if we wish to use an expression for this problem, let's start with a simple one and explore other options, maybe something similar to:

```
(.+=)?(.+?);
```

or

```
(.+=)?(.+?)(?:;.+)
```

where the second capturing group has our desired `word2`.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/7lvpiL/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/rqDjbP/1/)

#### Example 1

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(.+=)?(.+?);";
        string input = @"word1=word2;word3
word2;word3";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example 2

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(.+=)?(.+?)(?:;.+)";
        string substitution = @"$2";
        string input = @"word1=word2;word3
word2;word3";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expresions you can solve the problem with String class methods.

```
string[] words = str.Split(';');
string word2 = words[0].Substring(words[0].IndexOf('=') + 1);
```

First line splits the line from ';'. Assuming you just have a single ';' this statement splits your line into two strings. And second line returns a substring of first part (`words[0]`) starting from the first occurence of '=' (`words[0].IndexOf('=')`) character's next characher (`+1`) to the end. If your line doesn't have any '=' characters it just starts from the beginning because `IndexOf` returns -1.

Related documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8